Are 2 chain complexes isomorphic if their homology groups are isomorphic?
Given 2 chain complexes $(C^k, \partial^k)$ and $(\bar C^k, \bar \partial^k)$ with $\dim(C^k) = \dim(\bar C^k)$, does the isomorphism of the homology groups $H^k \cong \bar H^k$ imply the chain complexes are isomorphic?
I think the requirements for isomorphism of chain complexes can be narrowed down to the requirement that the 4 fundamental subspaces of $\partial^k$ have equal dimension to those of $\bar\partial^k$.
I can prove by induction that $\mathrm{nullity}(\partial^k)$ depends only on the dimensions of the spaces and the dimensions of the homology groups, which have equal values for both chain complexes. Therefore the $\mathrm{nullity}(\partial^k) = \mathrm{nullity}(\bar\partial^k)$, and the equivalence of rank, corank, and conullity follows from the fundamental theorem of linear algebra.
From the dimension of the homology group,
$$\dim(H^k) = \mathrm{nullity}(\partial^k) - \mathrm{rank}(\partial^{k+1})$$
and the rank-nullity theorem,
$$\mathrm{rank}(\partial^{k+1}) + \mathrm{nullity}(\partial^{k+1}) = \dim(C^{k+1})$$
the recursive formula for nullity is
$$\mathrm{nullity}(\partial^k) = \dim(C^k) + \dim(H^{k-1}) - \mathrm{nullity}(\partial^{k-1})$$
With the base case $\mathrm{nullity}(C^0) = \dim(C^0)$, and the conditions $\dim(C^k) = \dim(\bar C^k)$, $\dim(H^k) = \dim(\bar H^k)$, this is an inductive proof (I think) that the chain complexes are isomorphic. However induction doesn't work for infinite sequences, so this doesn't prove isomorphism between infinite chain complexes.
I really don't know if my proof is correct, but either way I would like to know the answer to my title question.
Thanks

What does "dim" mean? Are you working only with vector spaces?

You mention induction, but this doesn't work if the chain complexes are unbounded. Let $I$ be the chain complex of $k$-vector spaces
$$
0 \to \underset{0}{k} \xrightarrow{=} \underset{1}{k} \to 0.
$$
Now define
$$
C^\bullet = \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} I[2n]
$$
(where the square brackets indicate the shift operator) and
$$
\overline{C^\bullet} = \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} I[2n+1].
$$
Then both are exact, they have $\dim C^n = \dim \overline{C}^n$ for all $n$, but they are not isomorphic.
